# OTB-QGIS plugin does not appear in QGIS 3.2 after manual installation

Tags: qgis-3, orfeo-toolbox, otb-applications

I have followed [this instruction](https://gitlab.orfeo-toolbox.org/orfeotoolbox/qgis-otb-plugin) to connect the `qgis-otb-plugin` manually.

But after completing all the steps, OTB does not show under Settings > Options > Providers.

I cloned the `qgis-otb-plugin` repository with GitHub Desktop to c:\qgis-plugins\qgis-otb-plugin and set the `QGIS_PLUGINPATH` to the same path. Restarted. And then nothing. Can someone help?

Comment: I have tried in Ubuntu 18.04 with the same results. OTB is not listed in the plugin manager...

Comment: I get the same and have tried various options to no avail on Ubuntu 18.04!

This seems to detail a more in depth route:
https://wiki.orfeo-toolbox.org/index.php/QGIS_access_to_OTB_applications#Installing_the_plugins
But only for 14.04 ubuntu - so not helpful for 18.04

And this page mentions the issue at the bottom:
https://wiki.orfeo-toolbox.org/index.php/Quantum_GIS_plugins#Plugin_0.2

"Plugin does not appear anymore in the plugin manager of qgis : path of
a library use by the plugin is missing (add OTB's libraries path to
ld_library_path)"

Noted fix did not appear to fix it?

Comment: Installation steps have been updated to use more plugin manager in latest code. It works for QGIS <= 3.6. For 3.8 or higher otb provider is not a plugin. This is available now with default installation. (only need to install and configure otb)